# Tumblr ask page recaptcha glitch

Tags: html, iframe, blogs, tumblr

X post from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87311/tumblr-glitch-with-ask-page-captcha

I'm trying to let anonymous users post questions to my tumblr blog. My ask page requests users to pass recaptcha when posting questions anonymously, but if you try to open the element containing the recaptcha, it glitches up the view very badly, effectively rendering users unable to pass captcha.

[image]

There are no options in the edit HTML pane in Tumblr to change the recaptcha settings or modify the source. Is it acceptable to just create a new ask page on the add pages pane in Tumblr and edit that layout? I think the ask box is an `iframe`, so it's just a matter of making a bigger `iframe` show up instead of the default one.

Anyone run into this issue, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on this, I figured it out. Ended up doing another page, different from /ask, called /askme, on my site, and I wrote a bit of custom HTML to allow the iframe to scroll on resize of the captcha widget:

http://alfredo.moe/askme

```
<p>
<iframe frameborder="0" height="500" id="ask_form" scrolling="yes" src="https://www.tumblr.com/ask_form/alfredo.moe" width="100%" style="background-color: transparent; overflow: hidden;">
</iframe>
</p>
```

It bears noticing too, that apparently the issue has been fixed on the default ask form made by tumblr now. So, hooray to nonissues!

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yvgHHUp.png]

Answer (score 0):

On the ask page tumblr inserts an Iframe with insufficient height, but at least it has an id "ask_form" :-)

The only way I found to make the captcha visible is to override the given iframe height in css:

```
#ask_form { height: 550px !important; }
```

Comment: Before anyone chooses to [recommend deletion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11129935) of this post, this is a valid attempted answer. This post should not have been flagged and should not be recommended for deletion in the LQPRQ. See: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)